# MATCH with LOOKUP function

Tags: excel, function, match, lookup

I am looking for help with the following problem:

DATA spreadsheet: Raw data - contains balance sheet, income information, etc (several columns with dates on top)
Peer Comp spreadsheet: output table

I need the formula to return a value from the DATA spreadsheet to the Peer comp spreadsheet from the column that matched the date in the Peer Comp table. The caveat is that I need it to search the matching date first and then search for a matching description of the line item. For example, I need to return a value for “Net Sales” (row) for the date that matched a cell in the Peer Comp spreadsheet

Here is my current formula.
=INDEX(DATA!B3:M426,198,MATCH('Peer Comp'!B3,DATA!B3:M3,0))

Essentially, I just need to return value from a row labeled "Net Sales" (instead of a specific row number). In other words, I need to substitute "198" with a lookup for "Net Sales" exact match. Please Help!

Comment: Then use another MATCH() Formula in place of 198; `MATCH("Net Sales",A3:A426,0)`

Comment: ... or switch to a vlookup like `=VLOOKUP("Net Sales", DATA!A:M, MATCH('Peer Comp'!M3, DATA!3:3, 0), FALSE)`

Comment: If I use another MATCH in my current formula or VLOOKUP with the MATCH function in place of the column index, it returns #N/A. Is there something I need to put in front of the MATCH? Thanks for all the help.